# list S3 objects till only first level

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to list s3 obejcts like this:

```
for key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='bucketname')['Contents']:
    logger.debug(key['Key'])
```

I just want to print the folder names or file names that are present on the first layer.

For example, if my bucket has this:

```
bucketname
     folder1
     folder2
        text1.txt
        text2.txt
    catallog.json
```

I only want to print `folder1`, `folder2` and `catalog.json`. I don't want to include text1.txt etc.

However, my current solution also prints the files names present within the folders in my bucketname.

How can I modify this? I saw that there's a **'Prefix'** parameter but not sure how to use it.

Comment: If you can do it using the AWS cli then `aws s3 <bucketname>` will give you that but in boto you need to iterate over the keys.

Comment: You can use the s3 client or the resource to filter to the first '/' but the objects themselves would not be returned, e.g. `client.list_objects(Bucket=bucket_name,Delimiter='/')`, only returns the prefixes with first '/' and not objects in the bucket without a '/', using `boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name).objects.filter(Delimiter='/')` is how you'd do it w/a resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the keys on "/" and only keep the first level:

```py
level1 = set()  #Using a set removes duplicates automatically 
for key in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket='bucketname')['Contents']:
        level1.add(key["Key"].split("/")[0])  #Here we only keep the first level of the key 

#then print your level1 set
logger.debug(level1)
```

/!\ Warnings

1. `list_object` method has been revised and it is recommended to use `list_objects_v2` according to [AWS S3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects)
2. this method only returns some or all (up to 1,000) keys. If you want to make sure you get all the keys, you need to use the `continuation_token` returned by the function:

```py
level1 = set()
continuation_token = ""
while continuation_token is not None:
    extra_params = {"ContinuationToken": continuation_token} if continuation_token else {}
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket="bucketname", Prefix="", **extra_params)
    continuation_token = response.get("NextContinuationToken")
    for obj in response.get("Contents", []):
        level1.add(obj.get("Key").split("/")[0])

logger.debug(level1)
```

Comment: have you tried the first snippet? it gives me ```TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable```

Comment: my bad, i made a typo [ ] instead of ( ). I just fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

You use the `Delimiter` option, for example:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
BUCKET = "bucketname"

rsp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=BUCKET, Delimiter="/")

objects = [obj["Key"] for obj in rsp["Contents"]]
folders = [fld["Prefix"] for fld in rsp["CommonPrefixes"]]

for obj in objects:
    print("Object:", obj)

for folder in folders:
    print("Folder:", folder)
```

Result:

```
Object: catalog.json
Folder: folder1/
Folder: folder2/
```

Note that if you have a large number of keys at your top-level (over 1000) then you will need to [paginate](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Paginator.ListObjectsV2) your requests.

Also, note that [list_objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects) is essentially deprecated and you should use [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2).